# Getting correct Response.StatusCode from Application_OnError (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-codes, application-onerror

I'm trying to create some basic logging for unhandled exceptions in my ASP.NET MVC application, but as I'm using IIS6 all requests come through .NET. Now while I agree that missing images are an important thing to flag, they aren't show-stoppers and so I'd like to set the event priority to high for 404s unless they are images (which will get medium priority).

The problem is that in `Application_OnError` the `Response.StatusCode` is 200, but the final result sent out is 404. To this end, I don't seem to be able to watch out for 404s to set the appropriate priority.

Is there a way to tell what the `StatusCode` is *going* to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get it via `Context.Server.GetLastError()`:

```
if ((Context.Server.GetLastError() is HttpException) && ((Context.Server.GetLastError() as HttpException).GetHttpCode() == 404))
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to send all traffic through to the .net isapi layer and do a manual 404 check yourself (if file exists) I would imagine